# Node gives testnet error

Tags: baking, node, protocol, hardfork

rebooted my system and restarted the node. Now I'm getting the following error. Is this simply the node telling me that it's not able to run the new fork because I started it with the old (i.e. current) mainnet? not sure if I am able to bake or endorse (not an operation due for several hours) but I'd rather not find out the hard way. Any help understanding these errors would be appreciated.

```
Apr 13 15:11:36 - validator.chain(1): Error while switching test chain:

Apr 13 15:11:36 - validator.chain(1): Missing key in store: chain/7a06a770/blocks/91/cd/a5/db/92/b858926f1c84bc2028d5f4939967b1881113a70ac854d523a37126/contents

Apr 13 15:11:36 - validator.chain(1): Update current head to BMbep7Xh6kuET4r1G1odTYkYewefoNUFf99R7wnW8Ay7ymeksyg (fitness 00::0000000000bb4cc9), same branch

Apr 13 15:11:36 - validator.chain(1): Pushed: 2019-04-13T13:11:36Z, Treated: 2019-04-13T13:11:36Z, Completed: 2019-04-13T13:11:36Z
```

---

```
Apr 13 15:14:10 - p2p.connection: error writing to idtKG2F3ADLcGk57UYzcuQ1nxGPEWg

Apr 13 15:14:10 - p2p.connection:   Error, dumping error stack:

Apr 13 15:14:10 - p2p.connection:     Tezos_stdlib__Lwt_pipe.Closed

Apr 13 15:14:10 - p2p.connection:     IO error: connection with a peer is closed.

Apr 13 15:14:10 - p2p.connection:
```

Comment: Not only you experiencing this issue.

Comment: Would like to know the reason for this error   as well

Comment: I eliminated the error by rebooting system and updating the Tezos data with the usual commands.. Still don't know why I got the error in the first place

Comment: Can you be more specific about commands?

Comment: git fetch git reset --hard origin/mainnet git clean -dxf eval $(opam env) make build-deps make

Comment: So messages about test net disappeared?

Comment: Can you post the commands you used with semicolons? Otherwise it is not clear what they are since it is all in one line. Thanks

Comment: I believe you can write it all together like this

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me as well ! Node is up and running again. I think you should publish your solution as answer, because it really worked

Comment: I'm glad it did. The issue for me was, however, understanding why the error came up (and I missed my operation slot )

Comment: I missed lot of slots and some blocks because of this. If I will find the reason, I will let you know

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the cause is but here's how I got out of it without re-downloading the whole chain. You need to be running a version of `tezos-node` that supports snapshots such as the mainnet-snapshots branch.

Shutdown the `tezos-node` and any processes that depend on it like the baker, endorser and accuser if they're running.

The instructions assume that your `tezos-node` binary is in your path. If not, specify the correct path.

Export a snapshot:

```
tezos-node snapshot export tezos-snapshot
```

Backup the current `.tezos-node` directory.

```
mv -i ~/.tezos-node ~/.tezos-node-backup
```

Create a new `.tezos-node` directory and restore the identity

```
mkdir ~/.tezos-node
cp ~/.tezos-node-backup/identity.json ~/.tezos-node
```

Restore the snapshot

```
tezos-node snapshot import tezos-snapshot
```

Restore your other config files if you have some.

```
cp -i ~/.tezos-node-backup/config.json ~/.tezos-node-backup/peers.json  ~/.tezos-node
```

You can restart `tezos-node` now.

```
tezos-node run
```

And verify that the block height is increasing. (You'll need jq for this step)

```
tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/ | jq '.header.level, .header.timestamp';date
```